# HttpClient never times out when the network connection doesn't exist

Tags: c#, wpf, dotnet-httpclient

I have found that if the Network Adapter is 'disabled' before the call is executed or there doesn't happen to be any networking available the HttpClient never times out or throws an exception.

Below you will find an example of my code.

```
private static async Task<string> ExecuteHttpMethod(HttpMethod httpMethod, string url, object item)
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);

    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> responseTask = null;

    switch (httpMethod.Method)
    {
        case "GET":
        {
            responseTask = httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            break;
        }
        case "POST":
        {
            responseTask = httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(string.Format("{0} is not supported.", httpMethod.Method));
        }
    }

    try
    {
        responseTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string jsonResult = await responseTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return jsonResult;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Write(ex.ToString());
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

**Update 1 using `await`:**

```
HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
HttpResponseMessage responseTask = null;

switch (httpMethod.Method)
{
    case "GET":
    {
        responseTask =  await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        break;
    }
    case "POST":
    {
        responseTask = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent);
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(string.Format("{0} is not supported.", httpMethod.Method));
    }
}

try
{
    responseTask.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string jsonResult = await responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


    return jsonResult;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.Write(ex.ToString());
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: I meant to say instead of `await` (specifically in your switch statements).

Comment: I also tried using await previous to the GetAsync() method with the same results.

Comment: Can you post the code you have a problem with when you remove all instances of `.Result`?

Comment: Updated, removing all instances of .Result

Comment: Are you using this in a ASP.Net application?

Comment: Nope, this is a WPF appliation.

Comment: I get a AggregateException containing a HttpRequestException *An error occurred while sending the request*.  I only tested GET with a url of localhost to port 666.

Comment: It's worth noting that I've noticed *with* the `await` keyword, some requests will never complete.

Comment: It's not that it never completely, it [deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: In case anybody stumbles upon this question, this answer may provide some more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32195859/1305745